# Highlighting multiple hex_tiles by hovering in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I try to visualize my data in a hex map. For this I use python bokeh and the corresponding hex_tile function in the figure class. My data belongs to one of 8 different classes, each having a different color. The image below shows the current visualization:

[image: Current Visualization]
I would like to add the possibility to change the color of the element (and ideally all its class members) when the mouse hovers over it.

I know, that it is somewhat possible, as bokeh themselves provide the following example: 
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/hexbin.html

However, I do not know how to implement this myself (as this seems to be a feature for the hexbin function and not the simple hex_tile function)

Currently I provide my data in a ColumnDataSource:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
r=x_row,
q=y_col,
color=colors_array,
ipc_class=ipc_array
))
```

where "ipc_class" describes one of the 8 classes the element belongs to.
For the mouse hover tooltip I used the following code:

```
TOOLTIPS = [
("index", "$index"),
("(r,q)", "(@r, @q)"),
("ipc_class", "@ipc_class")
]
```

and then I visualized everything with:

```
p = figure(plot_width=1600, plot_height=1000, title="Ipc to Hexes with colors", match_aspect=True,
       tools="wheel_zoom,reset,pan", background_fill_color='#440154', tooltips=TOOLTIPS)
p.grid.visible = False
p.hex_tile('q', 'r', source=source, fill_color='color')
```

I would like the visualization to add a function, where hovering over one element will result in one of the following:
1. Highlight the current element by changing its color
2. Highlight multiple elements of the same class when one is hovered over by changing its color
3. Change the color of the outer line of the hex_tile element (or complete class) when the element is hovered over

Which of these features is possible with bokeh and how would I go about it?

EDIT:
After trying to reimplement the suggestion by Tony, all elements will turn pink as soon as my mouse hits the graph and the color won´t turn back. My code looks like this:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=x_row,
    y=y_col,
    color=colors_array,
    ipc_class=ipc_array
))

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=800, title="Ipc to Square with colors", match_aspect=True,
           tools="wheel_zoom,reset,pan", background_fill_color='#440154')
p.grid.visible = False
p.hex_tile('x', 'y', source=source, fill_color='color')

###################################

code = ''' 
for (i in cb_data.renderer.data_source.data['color'])
    cb_data.renderer.data_source.data['color'][i] = colors[i];

if (cb_data.index.indices != null) {
    hovered_index = cb_data.index.indices[0];
    hovered_color = cb_data.renderer.data_source.data['color'][hovered_index];
    for (i = 0; i < cb_data.renderer.data_source.data['color'].length; i++) {
        if (cb_data.renderer.data_source.data['color'][i] == hovered_color)
            cb_data.renderer.data_source.data['color'][i] = 'pink';
    }
}
cb_data.renderer.data_source.change.emit();
'''

TOOLTIPS = [
    ("index", "$index"),
    ("(x,y)", "(@x, @y)"),
    ("ipc_class", "@ipc_class")
]

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(colors=colors), code=code)
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=TOOLTIPS, callback=callback)
p.add_tools(hover)
########################################

output_file("hexbin.html")

show(p)
```

basically, I removed the tooltips from the figure function and put them down to the hover tool. As I already have red in my graph, I replaced the hover color to "pink". As I am not quite sure what each line in the "code" variable is supposed to do, I am quite helpless with this. I think one mistake may be, that my ColumnDataSource looks somewhat different from Tony's and I do not know what was done to "classifiy" the first and third element, as well as the second and fourth element together. For me, it would be perfect, if the classification would be done by the "ipc_class" variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following the discussion from previous post here comes the solution targeted for the OP code (Bokeh v1.1.0). What I did is:

1) Added a HoverTool

2) Added a JS callback to the HoverTool which:

- Resets the hex colors to the original ones (`colors_array` passed in the callback)
- Inspects the index of currently hovered hex (`hovered_index`)
- Gets the `ip_class` of currently hovered hex (`hovered_ip_class`)
- Walks through the `data_source.data['ip_class']` and finds all hexagons with the same `ip_class` as the hovered one and sets a new color for it (`pink`)
- Send `source.change.emit()` signal to the BokehJS to update the model

> The code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, HoverTool

colors_array = ["green", "green", "blue", "blue"]
x_row = [0, 1, 2, 3]
y_col = [1, 1, 1, 1]
ipc_array = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']

source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(
    x = x_row,
    y = y_col,
    color = colors_array,
    ipc_class = ipc_array
))

p = figure(plot_width = 800, plot_height = 800, title = "Ipc to Square with colors", match_aspect = True,
           tools = "wheel_zoom,reset,pan", background_fill_color = '#440154')
p.grid.visible = False
p.hex_tile('x', 'y', source = source, fill_color = 'color')

###################################
code = ''' 
for (let i in cb_data.renderer.data_source.data['color'])
    cb_data.renderer.data_source.data['color'][i] = colors[i];

if (cb_data.index.indices != null) {
    const hovered_index = cb_data.index.indices[0];
    const hovered_ipc_class = cb_data.renderer.data_source.data['ipc_class'][hovered_index];
    for (let i = 0; i < cb_data.renderer.data_source.data['ipc_class'].length; i++) {
        if (cb_data.renderer.data_source.data['ipc_class'][i] == hovered_ipc_class)
            cb_data.renderer.data_source.data['color'][i] = 'pink';
    }
}
cb_data.renderer.data_source.change.emit();
'''

TOOLTIPS = [
    ("index", "$index"),
    ("(x,y)", "(@x, @y)"),
    ("ipc_class", "@ipc_class")
]

callback = CustomJS(args = dict(ipc_array = ipc_array, colors = colors_array), code = code)
hover = HoverTool(tooltips = TOOLTIPS, callback = callback)
p.add_tools(hover)
########################################

output_file("hexbin.html")

show(p)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution. The explanation was really helpful. Before, I thought that the coloring was dependend on a specific class (as this was what my question asked) and I could not find this in your code. Now I saw, that you just skipped the class part and focused on the color, this makes sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: I connected `color` to `ipc_class` to make it more clear but you are right, they could be independent. See updated code.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this to start with (Bokeh v1.1.0):

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, HoverTool

colors = ["green", "blue", "green", "blue"]
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(r = [0, 1, 2, 3], q = [1, 1, 1, 1], color = colors))
plot = figure(plot_width = 300, plot_height = 300, match_aspect = True)
plot.hex_tile('r', 'q', fill_color = 'color', source = source)

code = ''' 
for (i in cb_data.renderer.data_source.data['color'])
    cb_data.renderer.data_source.data['color'][i] = colors[i];

if (cb_data.index.indices != null) {
    hovered_index = cb_data.index.indices[0];
    hovered_color = cb_data.renderer.data_source.data['color'][hovered_index];
    for (i = 0; i < cb_data.renderer.data_source.data['color'].length; i++) {
        if (cb_data.renderer.data_source.data['color'][i] == hovered_color)
            cb_data.renderer.data_source.data['color'][i] = 'red';
    }
}
cb_data.renderer.data_source.change.emit();
'''
callback = CustomJS(args = dict(colors = colors), code = code)
hover = HoverTool(tooltips = [('R', '@r')], callback = callback)
plot.add_tools(hover)
show(plot)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the first suggestion. However, after using this, all my elements turn immediatly to the hover color, as soon as the mouse hits the graph. I wrote something about that in an edit to the question. I would be happy, if you could take a look at it. Additionally, you import ColumnDataSource from bokeh.models, while I used bokeh.plotting beforehand. Is there a difference?

Comment: My example shows an approach. You cannot copy/paste it in your code without any adaptation. You should at least replace the callback args with `args = dict(colors = colors_array)` It always works the best when you provide a minimal but working code as one piece so others can run it and provide you a complete solution.

Comment: I know that, but sadly, I do not understand the approach, mostly the part in "code". Because of this, I am not able to transfer this to my case.I would be happy maybe with an explanation of what you actually did

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to update `cb_data.index.indices` to include all those indices that have `ipc_class` in common, and add `hover_color="pink"` to `hex_tile`. So in the `CustomJS` code one would loop the `ipc_class` column and get the indices that match the `ipc_class` of the currently hovered item.
In this setup there is not need to update the `color` column in the data source.

Code below tested used Bokeh version 3.0.2.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, HoverTool

colors_array = ["green", "green", "blue", "blue"]
x_row = [0, 1, 2, 3]
y_col = [1, 1, 1, 1]
ipc_array = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']

source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(
    x = x_row,
    y = y_col,
    color = colors_array,
    ipc_class = ipc_array
))

plot = figure(
    width = 800,
    height = 800, 
    title = "Ipc to Square with colors",
    match_aspect = True,
    tools = "wheel_zoom,reset,pan",
    background_fill_color = '#440154'
)
plot.grid.visible = False
plot.hex_tile(
    'x', 'y',
    source = source,
    fill_color = 'color',
    hover_color = 'pink' # Added!
)

code = '''
  const hovered_index = cb_data.index.indices;
  const src_data = cb_data.renderer.data_source.data;
  if (hovered_index.length > 0) {
    const hovered_ipc_class = src_data['ipc_class'][hovered_index];
    var idx_common_ipc_class = hovered_index;
    for (let i = 0; i < src_data['ipc_class'].length; i++) {
      if (i === hovered_index[0]) {
        continue;
      }
      if (src_data['ipc_class'][i] === hovered_ipc_class) {
        idx_common_ipc_class.push(i);
      }
    }
    cb_data.index.indices = idx_common_ipc_class;
    cb_data.renderer.data_source.change.emit();
  }
'''

TOOLTIPS = [
    ("index", "$index"),
    ("(x,y)", "(@x, @y)"),
    ("ipc_class", "@ipc_class")
]

callback = CustomJS(code = code)
hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips = TOOLTIPS,
    callback = callback
)
plot.add_tools(hover)

output_file("hexbin.html")
show(p)
```