# Highlighting country by hovering map using bokeh

Tags: python, dictionary, bokeh, interactive, choropleth

I'm trying to create a map similar to this one, but using Python (e.g. bokeh):
[8% of global deaths are the result of obesity](https://ourworldindata.org/obesity#8-of-global-deaths-are-the-result-of-obesity) (they used MySQL 5.7, Node 10.9+, and Yarn)

I can create a map, with some interactive functions, thanks to the following tutorials:

[A Complete Guide to an Interactive Geographical Map using Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-complete-guide-to-an-interactive-geographical-map-using-python-f4c5197e23e0)

[Walkthrough: Mapping Basics with bokeh and GeoPandas in Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/walkthrough-mapping-basics-with-bokeh-and-geopandas-in-python-43f40aa5b7e9)

You can see their codes and find the data.

The question is that how can I replicate two functions:

1. Highlight a country when I hover it?
2. Highlight all countries when I hover the bar (value range)?

For the first one, I tried to search for related materials, and here is one relevant:
[Highlighting multiple hex_tiles by hovering in bokeh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55947149/highlighting-multiple-hex-tiles-by-hovering-in-bokeh)

This is another one which may be the more relevant, but I'm not familiar with javascript:
[How To Build an Interactive Map with Open-Source Tools](https://www.jebruner.com/2011/11/how-to-build-an-interactive-map-with-open-source-tools/)

I appreciate it if anyone can help me with this. Thanks.

**Update on Jan 15:**
I basically solved the first issue (not exactly the same result); I'm still searching for the solution of 2nd question.

Comment: that link for the obesity map is brilliant. I am working in a personal project that has geodata, I have few maps done already with hovertool. I will work on it from here too, if I manage to get as close as possible of the samples, I will share here.[project](https://bokehflaskgcloud.appspot.com)